# Android MapActivity of mapsforge in tab

Tags: android, tabs, mapactivity

I tried to use `MapActivity` as tab but I always got an exception:

Generates  `Could not find class exception.` when tried to create

```
Intent mapTabIntent = new Intent(this, MapMF.class);
```

Why I got an exception?
As I analysed the rows of LogCat I realized a message with orange color : Unable to resolve superclass of com....MapMF.class where the  class MapMF extends MapActivity of mapsforge.

What did I do wrong?

If I use

`com.google.android.maps.MapActivity`

instead of

`org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity`

it works perfectly.

I don't understand why didn't work with MapActivity of mmapsforge.
Have somebody got any idea for resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem?

This is a perfectly logical conclusion.

`com.google.android.maps.MapActivity` is the package required to be importde

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity

Check out the Google Sample for a `MapActivity`. It also imports this

Comment: The problem is, with org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity as Tab page didn't work at all.
I would like to implement an off-line map to my app.

Comment: Of course the MapMF class imported.
The exact exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.....map.MapMF
If I add full namespace path for example com.myapp.mobile.appname.map.MapMF to each place where I use this class when tried to create intent I got same exception

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem was, a wrong order of libraries on Properties\Java Build Path\Order and Export.
I moved up the mapsforge library, to position below to my application and above the Google APIs [Android 2.2]